# Cross account sync not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am stumped.

I have a credential for account A: `arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT>:user/<USER>`

I have a bucket in account B: `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name`

Policy on the bucket in account B is set to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT>:user/<USER>"},
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`aws --profile <PROFILE> s3 ls s3://bucket-name`

fails with:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied`

I have tried 1001 variations on the policy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Access your IAM tab in your AWS console - Create a group - and when your group is created - create a policy with the following information:

```
{
   "Statement":{
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action":"s3:Get*",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket name/*"
   }
}
```

Make your IAM user a member of the group you created - any they will now have access to your S3 bucket in a separate AWS account.

**Edit**: As Pointed in Comment I Would like to Add Explanation that For this to work you need to have permission from Bucket Owner and User's Own Account before cross account access is allowed.

Thus What you might be missing is the permission from user's own account.

Comment: You might want to explain that this is necessary because a user requires permission from both the bucket owner account as well as the user's own account before cross-account access is allowed.  See also [How Amazon S3 Authorizes a Request for an Object Operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-auth-workflow-object-operation.html)

Comment: Also, you probably want to allow both the bucket and the objects as resources.    `"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*",
  "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name" ]`

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the user from the other account to that group.

Comment: Using the credential I have access to the source bucket.
`aws --profile <PROFILE> s3 ls s3://source-bucket`
Works correctly. The credential is from the other account.
I am attempting to grant that credential access in the destination account.

Answer (score 0):

`aws --profile <PROFILE> s3 ls s3://bucket-name` 
Double check your `PROFILE` here, maybe you are using wrong profile.

This is good article to read: [Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-s3/)

Comment: The profile works correctly against the source bucket in the other account.